# L298N motor controller board EN pins

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, pwm

[image]

For this device are the enable pins meant to be connected to PWM pins?
If so then how am I able to use this device with an arduino uno?
The uno does not have any pwm pins right?

Comment: the pins with ~. https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogwrite/

Answer (score 1):

The uno pins are 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11.

See https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogwrite/

Usage:

```cpp
analogWrite(pin, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

The people over at [How to Mechatronics](https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/arduino-dc-motor-control-tutorial-l298n-pwm-h-bridge/) have a great introduction to this board and using it with an Arduino Uno.

The enable pins are for turning the motors on and off. See the table for the different settings. [image: Enable pin truth table] But the EN pin is also used for controlling the motor speed.

PWM is used to adjust the speed the motors turn at. Rather than simply turning the enable pin fully “on” (i.e, full speed), PWM is used to adjust the voltage and thereby control the speed the motors turn.

So the short answer is yes, you can connect a PWM signal to the EN pins.  Yes a UNO can produce PWM (as answered by others)